# Error getting while publishing report to PUC

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

While I am publishing report from Pentaho Report Designer(PRD), I getting error like this "Unable to publish your file.Please try again or contact your administrator for assistance" on a dialog box. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Pentaho Report Designer is throwing the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.util.PublishException: The File exists and override has not been specified.
>       at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.UpdateReservedCharsTask.run(UpdateReservedCharsTask.java:81)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Unknown Source)
>       at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.PublishToServerTask.showErrorMessage(PublishToServerTask.java:172)
>       at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.PublishToServerTask.run(PublishToServerTask.java:115)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.util.PublishException: The File exists and override has not been specified.
>       at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.repository.actions.UpdateReservedCharsTask.run(UpdateReservedCharsTask.java:77)
>       ... 36 more

Comment: Please recheck the specified credentials. If it doesn't help, then try to send a GET request to `<your_pentaho_host>/<pentaho_context_root>/api/repo/files/reservedCharacters ` endpoint (e.g. open it in the browser) and add the result to your question.

Comment: What version of designer and server are used in above reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely not authorized to publish or providing incorrect credentials. Please note that the error message would be misleading if that's the case... you should ignore it and double-check your credentials and permissions against the target server.